# Не заходит «Hello World!» java, servlet, jsp

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Бьюсь и не могу справиться с простейшим, метод "printText" в классе Class, в сервлете request.setAttribute на JSP, выводит ошибку 500, гляньте код, что не так? Tomcat8, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Class, Servlet:

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    public class Print {
        public String printText() {
            return "Hello!";
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Print p = new Print();
        p.printText();
        request.setAttribute("p", p);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>${p.printText}</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

ошибка:

```
Made changes, but leads to errors

Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing JSP page [/index.jsp] at line [16]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/index.jsp] at line [16]

13:   </head>
14:   <body>
15:   <p>Connect to Server <a href="Servlet"> press</a></p>
16:   <p>Message: ${p.printText}</p>
17:   </body>
18: </html>


Stacktrace:
  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:19)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause
```

Comment: а зачем у вас в `public class Servlet` создан внутренний класс `PrintText`

Comment: Пардон, ошибочка при написании

Comment: возможно необходимо добавить гетер?

Comment: Вы в строке `PrintText p = new PrintText();` объявляете некий объект. Что это за объект что за класс? Есть ли у него метод `printText`. Дополните код.

Comment: внесены исправления)

Answer (score 1):

В строке:

```
16:   <p>Message: ${p.printText}</p>
```

JSP Пытается взять значение переменной `printText` у объекта `p`;
Но так как у вас это метод а не переменная, вы должны создать переменную, в нее внести то, что вам нужно и уже тогда вызывать.

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    public class Print {
        public String printText;
        public Print() {
            this.printText = "HelloWorld";
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Print p = new Print();
        p.printText();
        request.setAttribute("p", p);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```